# Plagiarism: quotation from videos course or conference

Tags: plagiarism

You know that there is large of youtube videos that talking about science (you can find conference videos, researchers recording research Methodology in a videotape, etc).

Let say that I am preparing to write an article for an international journal, and I take some of the phrases from what they saying, I used plagiarism software to check these phrases and I get  **Excellent, your content is 100% unique.** is this can be classified as plagiarism?

Comment: Plagiarism is not decided by a software. Plagiarism is the knowing use of others content/research and pass it as yours. So yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your question, you're "tak[ing] some of the phrases" from the videos. If you do not cite them, then you are guilty of plagiarism, since you are presenting the ideas and words of others as your own, which is essentially the definition of plagiarism. It doesn't matter that the text isn't written out. Stealing someone's oral statements is just as bad.